# Getting charts to start at the beginning of the window

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to plot the top 20 coins on one chart each with their own line. I have them showing but via their prices, they are all over the place and impossible to see. How can I get all of their charts to start on the left of my chart?

```
//@version=3
study("Top20Plotted", precision=1, overlay=true)

coinPrice = security(coin, period, close);



ethusdt  = security("COINBASE:ETHUSD", period, close)
xrpusdt  = security("Poloniex:XRPUSDT", period, close)
ltcusdt  = security("COINBASE:LTCUSD", period, close)
bchusd   = security("COINBASE:BCHUSD", period, close)
eosusdt  = security("Bitfinex:EOSUSD", period, close)
bnbusdt  = security("BINANCE:BNBUSDT", period, close)
xlmusdt  = security("BINANCE:BNBUSDT", period, close)
trxusdt  = security("BINANCE:TRXUSDT", period, close)
adausdt  = security("BINANCE:ADAUSDT", period, close)
xmrusdt  = security("BINANCE:XMRUSDT", period, close)
dashusdt = security("BITFINEX:DASHUSD", period, close)
atomusdt = security("BINANCE:ATOMUSDT", period, close)
linkusdt = security("BINANCE:LINKUSDT", period, close)
iotausdt = security("BINANCE:IOTAUSDT", period, close)
neousdt  = security("BINANCE:NEOUSDT", period, close)
etcusdt  = security("BINANCE:ETCUSDT", period, close)
xtzusdt  = security("BINANCE:XTZUSDT", period, close)



plot(ethusdt, color=aqua, style=line, title="ETH")
plot(xrpusdt, color=blue, style=line, title="XRP")
plot(ltcusdt, color=fuchsia, style=line, title="LTC")
plot(bchusd, color=gray, style=line, title="BCH")
plot(eosusdt, color=green, style=line, title="EOS")
plot(bnbusdt, color=lime, style=line, ttitle="BNB")
plot(xlmusdt, color=maroon, style=line, ttitle="xlm")
plot(trxusdt, color=navy, style=line, title="TRX")
plot(adausdt, color=olive, style=line, title="ADA")
plot(linkusdt, color=orange, style=line, title="LINK")
plot(iotausdt, color=purple, style=line, title="IOTA")
plot(neousdt, color=red, style=line, ttitle="NEO")
plot(etcusdt, color=silver, style=line, title="ETC")
plot(xtzusdt, color=teal, style=line, title="XTZ")
```

Comment: If some don't start at the left of your chart, it's because they have no history for those dates.

Comment: They start on the left but BTC starts at 1000 and IOTA starts at .004 so its impossible to see them on the same chart. I would like to get the price up with BTC. Similar to their "add a symbol" feature, but just have it be an indicator.

Comment: You could try putting your indicator on "no scale" with `study("Top20Plotted", precision=1, overlay=true, scale=scale.none)`. You will need to re-add the indie to see the effect. This will disconnect it from the price chart's scale. You can also achieve this through the *Pin to scale* choice of the indicator's dropdown menu. In any case, plotting signals with such different values will always be a challenge.